# jQuery, comments posted with quotes aren't working, otherwise it works great

Tags: java, jquery, html, coldfusion

If I post a comment like "hello there dog" it works great, but if there are any special characters like ' or " the comment is posted successfully to the database but the jQuery code is not displaying the comment in the list.

Thanks for any tips.

```
function feedbacksubmit () {
// Show the Ajax Loader
$("#ajaxloader").css("display","inline");
var textsubmitted = $("#feedbackinput").val();

if (textsubmitted.length < 5) {
    alert("Don't forget to write something!");
    // Hide the Ajax Loader
    $("#ajaxloader").css("display","none");
}
else {
    $.post("/feedback/ajax/insert/", {feedback: textsubmitted}, 
        function(data) {
            // Place the comment in the top of the list
            $('<li></li>').prependTo("#comment-list").hide().prepend(data.commenttext2insert).fadeIn('slow');
            // Hide the Ajax Loader
            $("#ajaxloader").css("display","none");
            // Clear out the textarea
            $("#feedbackinput").val('');
    }, "json");
}
}
```

Here is an example response that is not working with the jQuery code above:

```
{"returnmessage":"The Ajax operation was successful.","returncode":"0","commenttext2insert":"\n\t<div class=\"comment-header\">\n\t\t<span class=\"comment-avatar\">\n\t\t\t<a href=\"\">\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"/_images/users/photos//17941/nobosh.jpg\" />\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t</a>\n\t\t</span>\n\t\t<span class=\"comment-author\">\n\t\t\t<a href=\"\">\n\t\t\t\t<b>BOB Man</b>\n\t\t\t</a>\n\t\t</span>\n\t\t<span class=\"comment-timestamp\">just now</span>\n\t</div>\n\t<div class=\"comment-body\">\n\t\t<p>12wsa\'</p>\n\t</div>\n"}
```

Comment: What server side language are you using? Besides, have you considered returning a *real* JSON object and constructing HTML inside jQuery instead of returning JSON with server-prepared HTML?

Comment: I'm using Coldfusion... It's better not to use server prepared HTML? why's that?

Comment: JSON is great, but if you're returning HTML anyway it's just best to return it as HTML rather than JSON to reduce the unnecessary processing needed on both the server and client side and the code would be cleaner. Or as BalusC mentioned, you can go the other route and return JSON and build the HTML on the client side. All three technically work, but HTML over JSON is probably the most problematic to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your ColdFusion look like (at least the part where you return something to the browser)?  If BalusC is right about needing to escape html characters in your return data, you can just wrap your text with the HTMLEditFormat function rather than needing to write anything in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$.post("/feedback/ajax/insert/", {feedback: escape(textsubmitted)},
...
```

Comment: Question says: *the comment is posted successfully to the database* So I don't think that this is the problem ;)

Comment: Correct the comment is posted to the database succesfully. I tried this but it sends the comment back as 12weqdsa%27asdadasd%27

Answer (score 0):

If you're preparing HTML in the server side, you need to make sure that all reserved HTML characters in **user-controlled input** are properly escaped, else it may cause the JS code to become syntactically invalid (and make your website prone for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)). You need escape *at least* the reserved HTML characters `<`, `>`, `&`, `"` and `'` into HTML entities `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;` respectively.

You mentioned that you're using Coldfusion, which is Java based. As the standard Java SE/EE API doesn't provide builtin facilities to escape them, you'll need to either write one yourself, e.g.

```
public static final String escapeHTML(String string){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
            case '<': builder.append("&lt;"); break;
            case '>': builder.append("&gt;"); break;
            case '&': builder.append("&amp;"); break;
            case '"': builder.append("&quot;"); break;
            case '\'': builder.append("&apos;"); break;
            default: builder.append(c); break;
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

..which can be used as

```
input = escapeHTML(input);
```

..or to grab for example [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) which can be used as

```
input = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(input);
```

Once again, only do this for user-controlled input. You don't need to do this for any HTML code which you hardcoded in the server side code (else it would get displayed plain as-is). Thus do something like:

```
StringBuilder comment = new StringBuilder();
comment.append("<div class=\"comment\">");
comment.append(escapeHTML(input));
comment.append("</div>");
```

That said, I already commented in your question with the hint that you'd better to do this in jQuery, because that's after all much better for maintainability and reusability. You don't want to have raw HTML somewhere hidden in depths of Java code. You also don't want to make the JSON result dependent of the purpose. Just return a generic (and HTML-sanitized) JSON result and let jQuery build the HTML.